# cross product between vectors of different size

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have the two vectors `a, b` with shapes `(10,), (26,)` respectively.
I need to find the cross product between those two and the result must be of shape `(10, 26)`. I am using `numpy.cross()`.

I have tried reshaping and then computing the cross product. But not getting the desired shape.

Comment: sorry the result should be of shape(10,)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by cross product in this context. Do you mean you want each element to be multiplication of element i from a and element j from b?

Comment: Do you mean [outer product](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html)?

Comment: @Sara123 do put not fixes/additional info into comments, update the question instad.

Comment: `np.cross` is a special function for arrays with size 2 or 3 dimensions, producing a similar size array.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming my interpretation is correct (although I think technically you shouldn't call this a cross product), this will give you an element-wise multiplication matrix:

```
X = (a.reshape(-1,1) @ b.reshape(1,-1))
```

briefly, you are using a as columns and b as rows, and multiply each element row by column.